How to change textbox color based in sensor values?
I have an application in Android Studio and it is connected to an Arduino via Bluetooth. And I have a rectangle with a green color and I want it to change the color to red whenever the sensor value is greater than 0. I know that the application is receiving information since I have a text box and it is updating the correct values. What is the problem with the text color not updating?
I try to put a textbox to see if the bluetooth of arduino is sendind informatiton and yes he send
This is the code:
// Atualiza a TextView com o valor do sensor
private void updateSensorValue(String data) {
    Log.d("SensorData", "Atualizando valor: " + data);
    sensorValueText.setText("Valor do Sensor: " + data);
}

private void updateParkingValue(String data) {
    Log.d("ParkingData", "Atualizando valor do estacionamento: " + data);

    try {
        if (data != null && !data.isEmpty() && Integer.parseInt(data) > 0) {
            // Estacionamento Ocupado
            Log.d("ParkingData", "Estacionamento Ocupado");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    parkingLeftText.setText("Estacionamento Ocupado");
                    // Define a cor de fundo como vermelho (ocupado) usando a cor do colors.xml
                    parkingLeftText.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_occupied));  // Cor vermelha
                }
            });
        } else {
            // Estacionamento Livre
            Log.d("ParkingData", "Estacionamento Livre");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    parkingLeftText.setText("Estacionamento Livre");
                    // Define a cor de fundo como verde (livre) usando a cor do colors.xml
                    parkingLeftText.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_available));  // Cor verde
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Log.e("ParkingData", "Erro ao converter o valor: " + data, e);
    }
}


Your code is mostly okay, but the color is not changing.
Figuring out what could be wrong:
<color name="color_occupied">#FF0000</color> <!-- Red -->
<color name="color_available">#00FF00</color> <!-- Green -->

Check if you added these colors in your colors.xml file.
Maybe the data sent by the Arduino has extra spaces or weird characters. Fix this by adding data.trim() to clean the data before using it.
Integer.parseInt(data.trim()) > 0

Make sure parkingLeftText is the correct view.
Check your XML layout file and confirm you connected it properly in your code:
parkingLeftText = findViewById(R.id.parkingLeftText);

These could be the possible issues. Kindly check and let me know.
